# DoctrineExtensions error

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I'm trying to configure https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions
with the instruction https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/annotations.md#em-setup

But I get an error:

```
The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass" in class Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded\MappedSuperclass" in class Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

My configs

```
define('DB_CONNECTION', "host= ....");

$file_text_lib = __DIR__ . "/../../vendor/autoload.php";

require_once($file_text_lib);

// bootstrap.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper;


use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Doctrine\ORM\Version;
//use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper;

define(
"PARSE_CONNECTION_STRING_REGEXP",
"/(\s*host\s*=\s*(?P<host>[^\s]+)|\s*port\s*=\s*(?P<port>[\d]+)|\s*dbname\s*=\s*(?P<dbname>[^\s]+)|\s*user\s*=\s*(?P<user>[^\s]+)|\s*password\s*=\s*(?P<password>[^\s]+)\s*)*/"
);


$isDevMode = true;


// globally used cache driver, in production use APC or memcached
$cache = new Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache;
// standard annotation reader
$annotationReader = new Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
$cachedAnnotationReader = new Doctrine\Common\Annotations\CachedReader(
    $annotationReader, // use reader
    $cache // and a cache driver
);
// create a driver chain for metadata reading
$driverChain = new Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain();
// load superclass metadata mapping only, into driver chain
// also registers Gedmo annotations.NOTE: you can personalize it
Gedmo\DoctrineExtensions::registerAbstractMappingIntoDriverChainORM(
    $driverChain, // our metadata driver chain, to hook into
    $cachedAnnotationReader // our cached annotation reader
);

// now we want to register our application entities,
// for that we need another metadata driver used for Entity namespace

$ymlDriver = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver(array(__DIR__."/YAMLMetaConfiguration"));

$driverChain->addDriver($ymlDriver, 'SemanticPersistence\\Entities');


// general ORM configuration
$config = new Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__ . "/../Proxies");
$config->setProxyNamespace('SemanticPersistence\\Proxies');
$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses($isDevMode); // this can be based on production config.
// register metadata driver
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverChain);
// use our already initialized cache driver
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl($cache);
$config->setQueryCacheImpl($cache);


$evm = new Doctrine\Common\EventManager();

// timestampable
$timestampableListener = new Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener;
$timestampableListener->setAnnotationReader($cachedAnnotationReader);
$evm->addEventSubscriber($timestampableListener);





//$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__ . "/Entities"), $isDevMode, null, null, false);
// or if you prefer yaml or XML
//$config = Setup::createXMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/config/xml"), $isDevMode);
/*
$config = Setup::createYAMLMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/YAMLMetaConfiguration"), $isDevMode);

$config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);

$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__ . "/../Proxies");
$config->setProxyNamespace('SemanticPersistence\\Proxies');
*/


preg_match(
    PARSE_CONNECTION_STRING_REGEXP,
    DB_CONNECTION,
    $matches
);

$dbParams = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_pgsql',
    'user' => $matches['user'],
    'password' => $matches['password'],
    'host' => $matches['host'],
    'dbname' => $matches['dbname'],
    'charset' => 'UTF-8'
);

if (!empty($matches['port'])) {
    $dbParams['port'] = $matches['port'];
}

$entityManager = Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config, $evm);


$helperSet = new HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new ConnectionHelper($entityManager->getConnection()),
    'em' => new EntityManagerHelper($entityManager),
    'dialog' => new QuestionHelper(),
));

$commands = array(
    // DBAL Commands
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\RunSqlCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Command\ImportCommand(),

    // ORM Commands
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ClearCache\MetadataCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ClearCache\ResultCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ClearCache\QueryCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\CreateCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\UpdateCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\DropCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\EnsureProductionSettingsCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ConvertDoctrine1SchemaCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateRepositoriesCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateEntitiesCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\GenerateProxiesCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ConvertMappingCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\RunDqlCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ValidateSchemaCommand(),
    new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\InfoCommand(),
    //new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\MappingDescribeCommand(),

);


$cli = new Application('Doctrine Command Line Interface', Version::VERSION);


$cli->setCatchExceptions(true);
$cli->setHelperSet($helperSet);

$cli->addCommands($commands);

$cli->run();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to ensure standard doctrine annotations are registered

```
Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerFile(
    __DIR__.'/../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DoctrineAnnotations.php'
);
```